# Persistent gutter around images - How to remove?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, gutter

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1 and have read the former responses to this issue, but space around images is still there.

I'm very new to Bootstrap and only have experience with html before that.

What am I missing?

```
<main class="bd-masthead" id="content" role="main">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
      <div class="col no-gutters">
        <a href="profile001.html">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" style="width:100%" alt="profile Wu">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col no-gutters">
          <a href="profile002.html">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" style="width:100%" alt="profile Lin">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col no-gutters">
            <a href="profile002.html">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placekitten.com/200/140" style="width:100%" alt="profile Liu">
            </a>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: What are you talking about "have read the former responses to this issue"?

Comment: There are other posts on bootstrap and gutter formatting here. I've read them before posting.

Comment: We don't know what you've tried when you say that. We need a [mcve] in your question and all you've provided is the HTML.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you (a) Used the live demo feature of Stackoverflow (b) Included the bootstrap CSS and (c) Used URLs to images that resolve (you might find https://placekitten.com/ useful)

Comment: Ok, the "no gutters" formatting in this html is the attempt, on this piece of html, to remove the space between images in this grid. That's not working. Apart from this html code the only info I`d have are the images themselves.

Comment: @user2395805 — The backtick character is used for marking content as *code* in comments (and posts). Don't use it as an apostrophe. Use a real `'` or `’` instead.

Comment: what is this live demo feature? i can't seem to find it

Comment: already fixed the apostrophe

Comment: on the css, I havent customized anything, working only with the html file